# Can an ANN of 2 neurons solve XOR?

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, xor

I know that an artificial neural network (ANN) of 3 neurons in 2 layers can solve XOR

```
Input1----Neuron1\
       \ /        \
       / \         +------->Neuron3
      /   \       /
Input2----Neuron2/
```

But to minify this ANN, can just 2 neurons (Neuron1 takes 2 inputs, Neuron2 take only 1 input) solve XOR?

```
Input1
      \
       \ Neuron1------->Neuron2
       / 
Input2/
```

> The artificial neuron receives one or more inputs...
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neuron

Bias input '1' is assumed to be always there in both diagrams.

> *Side notes:*
>
> Single neuron can solve xor but with additional input x1*x2 or x1+x2
>   https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-the-XOR-problem-be-solved-by-a-one-layer-perceptron/answer/Razvan-Popovici/log
>
> The ANN form in second diagram may solve XOR with additional input like above to Neuron1 or Neuron2?

Comment: Don't you need two inputs for XOR?

Comment: `I know that an artificial neural network (ANN) of 3 neurons in 2 layers can solve XOR` Could you provide a sketch of (or reference for) that solution? `But to minify this ANN, can just 2 neurons solve XOR?` (minimise?) layered or non-layered?

Comment: "minify this ANN" = reduce number of neurons

Comment: Your edit clarifies the problem much better now. Neuron2 has limited function in the second diagram. Whatever value it responds with can be closely approximated by removing it and changing the weights and bias of the network, so the second diagram is only one functional layer that synthesizes values together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible. But before solving XOR problem with two neurons I want to discuss on linearly separability. A problem is linearly separable if only one hyperplane can make the decision boundary. (Hyperplane is just a plane drawn to differentiate the classes. For an N dimensional problem i.e, a problem having N features as inputs the hyperplane will be an N-1 dimensional plane.) So for a 2 input XOR problem the hyperplane will be an one dimensional plane that is a "line".

Now coming to the question, XOR is not linearly separable. Hence we cannot directly solve XOR problem with two neurons. Following images show no matter how many ways we draw a line in 2D space we cannot differentiate one side's output with the other. For example for the first one (0,1) and (1,0) both inputs makes XOR to give 1. But for the input (1,1) the output is 0 but we cannot make it separated and unfortunately they are falling in the same side.

[image]

So here we have two options to solve it:

1. Using hidden layer. But it will increase the number of neurons more than two.
2. Another option is to **increase the dimensions**.

Let's have an illustration how increasing dimensions can solve this problem keeping the the number of neurons 2.

For an analogy we can think XOR as a subtraction of AND from OR like below,

[image: Truth table]

[image: Here is the diagram]

If you notice the upper figure, the first neuron will mimic logical AND after passing "v=(-1.5)+(x1*1)+(x2*1)" to some activation function and the output will be considered as 0 or 1 depending on v is negative or positive respectively (I am not getting into the details...hope you got the point). And the same way the next neuron will mimic logical OR.

So for the first three cases of the truth table the AND neuron will remain turned off. But for the last one (actually where OR is different from XOR) the AND neuron will be turned on providing a big negative value to the OR neuron which will overwhelm the total summation to negative as it is big enough to make the summation a negative number. So finally activation function of the second neuron will interpret it as 0.

By this way we can make XOR with 2 neurons.

Following two figures are also the solutions to your questions which I have collected:

[image]
[image]

Comment: tks, i swapped the answer to this

Answer (score 8):

No that's not possible, *unless* (maybe) you start using some rather strange, unusual activation functions.

Let's first ignore neuron 2, and pretend that neuron 1 is the output node. Let `x0` denote the bias value (always `x0 = 1`), and `x1` and `x2` denote the input values of an example, let `y` denote the desired output, and let `w1, w2, w3` denote the weights from the `x's` to neuron 1. With the XOR problem, we have the following four examples:

- `x0 = 1, x1 = 0, x2 = 0, y = 0`
- `x0 = 1, x1 = 1, x2 = 0, y = 1`
- `x0 = 1, x1 = 0, x2 = 1, y = 1`
- `x0 = 1, x1 = 1, x2 = 1, y = 0`

Let `f(.)` denote the activation function of neuron 1. Then, assuming we can somehow train our weights to solve the XOR problem, we have the following four equations:

- `f(w0 + x1*w1 + x2*w2) = f(w0) = 0`
- `f(w0 + x1*w1 + x2*w2) = f(w0 + w1) = 1`
- `f(w0 + x1*w1 + x2*w2) = f(w0 + w2) = 1`
- `f(w0 + x1*w1 + x2*w2) = f(w0 + w1 + w2) = 0`

Now, the main problem is that activation functions that are typically used (ReLUs, sigmoid, tanh, idendity function... maybe others) are nondecreasing. That means that if you give it a larger input, you also get a larger output: `f(a + b) >= f(a)` if `b >= 0`. If you look at the above four equations, you'll see this is a problem. Comparing the second and third equations to the first tell us that `w1` and `w2` need to be positive because they need to increase the output in comparison to `f(w0)`. But, then the fourth equation won't work out because it will give an even greater output, instead of `0`.

I think (but didn't actually try to verify, maybe I'm missing something) that it would be possible if you use an activation function that goes up first and then down again. Think of something like `f(x) = -(x^2)` with some extra term to shift it away from the origin. I don't think such activation functions are commonly used in neural networks. I suspect they'll behave less nicely when training, and are not plausible from a biological point of view (remember than neural networks are at least inspired by biology).

Now, in your question you also added an extra link from neuron 1 to neuron 2, which I ignored in the discussion above. The problem here is still the same though. The activation level in neuron 1 is always going to be higher than (or at least as high as) the second and third cases. Neuron 2 would typically again have a nondecreasing activation function, so would not be able to change this (unless you put a negative weight between the hidden neuron 1 and output neuron 2, in which case you flip the problem around and will predict too high a value for the first case)

---

EDIT: Note that this is related to Aaron's answer, which is essentially also about the problem of nondecreasing activation functions, just using more formal language. Give him an upvote too!

Comment: thanks, your answer is clear enough, that means it's not possible for traditional layered network. However, what if in the second diagram, Neuron1 takes 2 inputs as usual, Neuron2 takes 3 inputs (input1, input2, and the output of Neuron1)? i know connecting neurons this way is not traditional layered network and backpropagation process is not the same too, but it may be a new solution?

Comment: @johnlowvale Intuitively, I think so. In your original example, the single connection between neurons 1 and 2 doesn't really change anything in terms of what functions can be approximated. I suspect that in the same way, the structure in your new question can be extended by placing an extra hidden neuron between inputs 1 and 2 on the left, and neuron 2 on the right, without really influencing what kinds of functions can be approximated. And that would be the well known network with hidden layer of 2 nodes. It may train more slowly though. Best way to make sure is to implement and try though!

Comment: i've change the answer to possible, with feeding input to second neuron

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible.

Firstly, you need an equal number of inputs to the inputs of XOR. The smallest ANN capable of modelling *any* binary operation will contain two inputs. The second diagram only shows one input, one output.

Secondly, and this is probably the most direct refutation, the XOR function's output is not an additive or multiplicative relationship, but can be modelled using a combination of them. A neuron is generally modelled using functions like sigmoids or lines which have no [stationary points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point), so one layer of neurons can roughly approximate an additive or multiplicative relationship.

What this means is that **a minimum of two layers of processing are required to produce a XOR operation**.

---

This question brings up an interesting topic of ANNs. They are well-suited to identifying *fuzzy* relationships, but tend to require *at least* as much network complexity as any mathematical process which would solve the problem with no fuzzy margin for error. Use ANNs where you need to identify something which looks *mostly* like what you are identifying, and use math where you need to know *precisely* whether something matches a set of concrete traits.

Understanding the distinction between ANN and mathematics opens up the possibility of combining the two in more powerful calculation pipelines, such as identifying possible circles in an image using ANN, using mathematics to pin down their precise origins, and using a second ANN to compare those origins to the configurations on known objects.

Comment: input layer is not included in my question

Comment: Have two neurons connected to both inputs with weight 1, "front" with a threshold 2, connected to the third input of "out" with a weight of -2 and a threshold of 1 - just _not_ layered _and using a negative weight_.

Comment: @greybeard That's a noteworthy case, though it moves away from the assumptions of many ANN models I'm aware of. To an extent, it's a great exercise to bend the models in use to meet certain cases better, even though it's often not enough general improvement to be justified.

Answer (score 3):

It is absolutely possible to solve the XOR problem with only two neurons.

Take a look at the model below.

[image]

This model solves the problem easily. 
The first representing logic AND and the other logic OR. The value of +1.5 for the threshold of the hidden neuron insures that it will be turned on only when both input units are on. The value of +0.5 for the output neuron insures that it will turn on only when it receives a net positive input greater than +0.5. The weight of -2 from the hidden neuron to the output one insures that the output neuron will not come on when both input neurons are on (ref. 2).

ref. 1: Hazem M El-Bakry, Modular neural networks for solving high complexity problems ([link](http://%20https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4030251))

ref. 2: D. E. Rumelhart, G. E. Hinton, and R. J. Williams, Learning representation by error backpropagation, Parallel distributed processing: Explorations in the Microstructures of Cognition, Vol. 1, Cambridge, MA: MIT Press, pp. 318-362, 1986.

Comment: tks, this is also a solution

Answer (score -1):

The problem can be split in two parts.

Part one
a  b  c
-------
0  0  0
0  1  1
1  0  0
1  1  0

Part two
a  b  d
-------
0  0  0
0  1  0
1  0  1
1  1  0

Part one can be solved with one neuron.
Part two can also be solved with one neuron.

part one and part two added together makes the XOR.

c = sigmoid(a * 6.0178 + b * -6.6000 + -2.9996)
d = sigmoid(a * -6.5906 + b *5.9016 + -3.1123 )

----------------------------------------------------------

sigmoid(0.0 * 6.0178 + 0 * -6.6000 + -2.9996)+ sigmoid(0.0 * -6.5906 + 0 *5.9016 + -3.1123 ) = 0.0900

sigmoid(1.0 * 6.0178 + 0 * -6.6000 + -2.9996)+ sigmoid(1.0 * -6.5906 + 0 *5.9016 + -3.1123 ) = 0.9534

sigmoid(0.0 * 6.0178 + 1 * -6.6000 + -2.9996)+ sigmoid(0.0 * -6.5906 + 1 *5.9016 + -3.1123 ) = 0.9422

sigmoid(1.0 * 6.0178 + 1 * -6.6000 + -2.9996)+ sigmoid(1.0 * -6.5906 + 1 *5.9016 + -3.1123 ) = 0.0489

Comment: Please add an explanation of how this answers the question. It looks rather unclear to me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).